# Не могу разобраться с ошибкой Имя " " не существует в текущем контексте. Язык C#. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c#, массивы, классы, объекты

Выдается такая ошибка: Имя "Lampaas[i]" не существует в текущем контексте. Ошибки который выделил Visual Studio, выделена звёздочкой(*), точнее где написано Lampaas[i] и Lampass[b] ошибка. Язык C#. Я сортирую объекты по возрастанию и все сортируется по полю public int capacitylamp { get; set; }.

```
using System;
namespace Laba_6
{
    class Lampa : IComparable<Lampa>
    {
        public string typelamp { get; set; }
        public int capacitylamp { get; set; }
        public int c_outlamp { get; set; }

        public Lampa(string typelamp, int capacitylamp, int c_outlamp)
        {
            this.typelamp = typelamp;
            this.capacitylamp = capacitylamp;
            this.c_outlamp = c_outlamp;
        }

        public int CompareTo(Lampa p)
        {
            return this.capacitylamp.CompareTo(p.capacitylamp);
        }
        class Lamps
        {
            Lampa[] Lampas = new Lampa[7];
            public Lampa this[int pos]
            {
                get
                {
                    if (pos >= 0 || pos < 7) return Lampas[pos];
                    else throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Вне диапазона!");
                }
                set { Lampas[pos] = value; }
            }
        }

        class Program
        {
            public void Print()
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 7; b++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Тип лампы: **{Lampaas[b]**.typelamp}. Потребляемая мощность: {**Lampaas[b]**.capacitylamp} Вт. Выходная мощность {**Lampaas[b]**.c_outlamp} Вт.");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
            public void Sort_select() // сортировка методом прямого выбора
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    int min = i;
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++)
                    {
                        if (**Lampaas[i]**.CompareTo(**Lampaas[j]**) > 0)
                        {
                            min = j;
                        }
                    }
                    var temp = **Lampaas[i]**;
                    **Lampaas[i]** = **Lampaas[min]**;
                    **Lampaas[min]** = temp;

                }
            }

            public void Sortbubble()
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++)
                    {
                        if (**Lampaas[i]**.CompareTo(**Lampaas[j]**) > 0)
                        {
                            var t = **Lampaas[i];**
                            **Lampaas[i]** = **Lampaas[j]**;
                            **Lampaas[j]** = t;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Lamps Lampaas = new Lamps();
                Lampaas[0] = new Lampa("Накаливание", 100, 100);
                Lampaas[1] = new Lampa("Светодиодная", 20, 100);
                Lampaas[2] = new Lampa("Люминесцентные", 50, 100);
                Lampaas[3] = new Lampa("Галогенная", 150, 150);
                Lampaas[4] = new Lampa("Газоразрядные", 110, 150);
                Lampaas[5] = new Lampa("Энергосберегающая", 15, 100);
                Lampaas[6] = new Lampa("Неоновая", 250, 350);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Program sort = new Program();
                //sort.Print();
                //sort.Sort_select();
                sort.Sortbubble();
                sort.Print();
                Console.WriteLine();
                sort.Sort_select();   
                sort.Print();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        static Lamps Lampaas = new Lamps();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Lamps Lampaas = new Lamps();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @ils2 Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.